# GSON serialization with number

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I faced a problem with json serialization with Gson.

The return looks like this:

```
{"STATUS":200,
"ORG_NAME":"FF Superflott",
"VORNAME":"Christian",
"NACHNAME":"Tschimmi",
"PERSONEN":[{"personenID":2,
  "dienstgrad":"General",
  "vorname":"Max",
  "nachname":"Mustermann",
  "handynummer":"0680\/216 34 21"},
  {"personenID":2732,
  "dienstgrad":"",
  "vorname":"Vorname35",
  "nachname":"Name 1",
  "handynummer":"0664 4677567"}],
"GRUPPEN":{"1":"Feuer",
  "2":"SA1",
  "3":"SA2",
 ...
  "28":"",
  "29":"",
  "30":""}}
```

My Model looks like this:

```
data class TestModel (
    @SerializedName("STATUS") val STATUS: Int,
    @SerializedName("ORG_NAME")  val ORG_NAME : String,
    @SerializedName("VORNAME")  val VORNAME : String,
    @SerializedName("NACHNAME")  val NACHNAME : String,
    @SerializedName("PERSONEN")  val PERSONEN : ArrayList<PERSONEN> = arrayListOf(),
    @SerializedName("GRUPPEN")  val GRUPPEN : ArrayList<GRUPPEN> = arrayListOf(),
 
)

data class PERSONEN (
    @SerializedName("personenID"  ) var personenID  : Int?    = null,
    @SerializedName("dienstgrad"  ) var dienstgrad  : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("vorname"     ) var vorname     : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("nachname"    ) var nachname    : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("handynummer" ) var handynummer : String? = null
)

data class GRUPPEN (
    @SerializedName("1"  ) var 1 : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("2"  ) var 2  : String? = null,
   ...
    @SerializedName("29" ) var 29 : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("30" ) var 30 : String? = null


)
```

I get an error about conflict declaration.
The problem should be the key in the "GRUPPEN" section.
This keys are String but recognised as Int.

ErrorMessage: `Conflicting declarations: public final var` `: String?, public final var` `: String?`

Does somewhere know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please post full description of the error

Comment: Error Message: Conflicting declarations: public final var `<no name provided>`: String?, public final var `<no name provided>`: String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables can't start with numbers.  You need to give it a name other than "1".  The serialized name can be "1" however, which will make it work.

Also, if the variable name and the serialized name are the same, there's no reason for the annotation.  You can delete all those.

Comment: "there's no reason for the annotation", except if you want to make sure ProGuard or R8 doesn't rename or remove these fields (unless you annotate the whole class with `@Keep` or have custom rules).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gabe Sechan for the fast answer.
I changed to:

```
data class GRUPPEN (
    @SerializedName("1"  ) var g1 : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("2"  ) var g2  : String? = null,
 ...
    @SerializedName("29" ) var g29 : String? = null,
    @SerializedName("30" ) var g30 : String? = null
)
```

and I had a mistake in GRUPPEN declaration:

```
@SerializedName("GRUPPEN") var GRUPPEN : GRUPPEN? = GRUPPEN(),
```

Now it works.
Thank you very much again!